# Xlsx file not generating for the dynamic data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have one table data. Which contains date column. Here what I'm doing is, I'm passing my selected date to servlet. Using that date I'm getting some records from the table. Then I'm creating a workbook called Microsoft Excel file using Apache POI and storing that data into excel file.

Here is my code:

```
String reports_date = request.getParameter("reports_date");

    //CreateJobOrderBean joborderbean = new CreateJobOrderBean();
    BSUtils bsutils = new BSUtils();

            //Received Date format: 09-Dec-2015(dd-MMM-yyyy)
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date date = null;
            String formatteddate = null;
                try {
                    date = formatter.parse(reports_date);
                    formatteddate = formatter1.format(date);
                    date = formatter1.parse(formatteddate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
              XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("JobOrders Data");
              XSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(1);
              XSSFCell cell;
              cell=row.createCell(1);
              cell.setCellValue("owner_name");
              cell=row.createCell(2);
              cell.setCellValue("owner_tel1");
              cell=row.createCell(3);
              cell.setCellValue("location");
              cell=row.createCell(4);
              cell.setCellValue("postcode");
              cell=row.createCell(5);
              cell.setCellValue("nature_of_case");
              cell=row.createCell(6);
              cell.setCellValue("cause");
              cell=row.createCell(7);
              cell.setCellValue("assign_to_mktg");
              cell=row.createCell(8);
              cell.setCellValue("assign_to_qs");
              cell=row.createCell(9);
              cell.setCellValue("job_created_on");

             int i=2;
              List<CreateJobOrderBean> reports_data = bsutils.getReportsDate(date);
              System.out.println(reports_data.size());
             for (int j = 0; j < reports_data.size(); j++) {
                 row=spreadsheet.createRow(i);
                 cell=row.createCell(1);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getOwnername());
                 cell=row.createCell(2);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getTel1());
                 cell=row.createCell(3);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getLocation());
                 cell=row.createCell(4);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getPostcode());
                 cell=row.createCell(5);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getNatureofcase());
                 cell=row.createCell(6);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getCause());
                 cell=row.createCell(7);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getAssignedmarketingemail());
                 cell=row.createCell(8);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getAssignedQs());
                 cell=row.createCell(9);
                 cell.setCellValue(reports_data.get(j).getJobCreatesOnasString());
                 i++;
              }
              FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/joborders_database.xlsx"));
              workbook.write(out);
              out.close();
```

This code running successfully,but xlsx file is not generating. I don't know where I did the mistake.

Comment: Code looks fine, file may be generated at any other location ? if you are using eclipse or netbeans then please check project directory (workspace). Try to search the file with file name "joborders_database.xlsx", any ways your code looks fine.

Comment: I searched joborders_database.xlsx file, but didn't find that any where in my system @nikeshjoshi. I'm using eclipse LUNA.

Comment: As I see your code is fine, put try-catch block and then see if it is throwing any  exception.

Comment: In servlet add try catch block and catch Exception , print stacktrace of the exception and see.

Comment: yes i got the answer@nikeshjoshi. I was changed the file path. It is not storing in project directory and C drive also. I was added D drive in the path, then the file is generated.Thank you for your help@nikeshjoshi.